# gin bindJson array of objects

Tags: go, go-gin

I would like to bind a json array of objects like this one :

```
[
    {
        "id": "someid"
    },
    {
        "id": "anotherid"
    }
]
```

Here my model

```
type DeleteByID struct {
    ID string `json:"id" binding:"required"`
}
```

I use gin to handle the object

```
var stock []DeleteByID
if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&stock); err != nil {
 return err
}
```

The problem is that it does not bind/check my object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `json.Unmarshal()` like this:

```
var stock []DeleteByID

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(400, err)
    return
}

err = json.Unmarshal(body, &stock)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(400, err)
    return
}

c.String(200, fmt.Sprintf("%#v", stock))
```

Comment: Indeed it works, I hoped I could use the ShouldBind because it returns an error if the object isn't "correct". Instead I need to loop over the stock variable and check if the id is empty or not. Hoping it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is to pass the array as a nested field. When marked with "dive", gin will bind and validate. These ones will cause an error:

```
{
  "Deletions": [    {
        "id": 13
    },
    {
    }
  ]
}
```

This is acceptable input:

```
{
  "Deletions": [
    {
        "id": "someid"
    },
    {
        "id": "anotherid"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here my model

```
type DeleteByID struct {
    ID string `json:"id" binding:"required"`
}

type DeletePayload struct {
    Deletions []DeleteByID `binding:"dive"`
}
```

The `dive` keyword will ensure that the JSON array is validated as it becomes a slice, map or array.

```
var stock DeletePayload
if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&stock); err != nil {
 return err
}
```

See this issue for some more details: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/3238